# Is there a reason to keep the express variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As a relatively new developer, I don't see any reason to create or keep the express variable around in an express/Node app.

Instead of:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Why not just do this:

```
const app = require('express')();
```

Comment: You can, nothing's stopping you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly reasonable to use that as an all in one statement. However,as has been mentioned, it may come in useful with `express.static()` being used for creating static paths for public files(images etc). There are other uses of the express variable. And calling `var app = require("express")();` is fine if you don't need those.

Trimming off that extra line shouldn't change much, the module will still be fully required.

Answer (score 0):

As with any other variable the reason is, that you might need to use it later. If you won't, then don't.

For example, something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(staticAssetsPath));
```